# Как удалять временную папку, которая создаётся от pyinstaller

Tags: python

Я написал скрипт и скомпилировал его с помощью pyinstaller.

Этот скрипт бесконечно работает в фоне.

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы временная папка, которая создаётся при запуске exe файла, удалялась после завершения скрипта.

```
from keyboard import add_hotkey
from os import startfile


def start():
    startfile(r'C:\Users\neptu\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9016\Discord.exe')


add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+8', start)

while True:
    pass
```

При запуске exe файла (скомпилированного с помощью pyinstaller) создаётся временная папка. Я хочу её удалять после закрытия скрипта, но не знаю как это сделать в коде (что бы удалить папку, я использую shutil.rmtree, но я не знаю куда это прописать в коде)

Comment: А какое будет завершение скрипта, если он работает бесконечно?

Comment: @wchistow принудительное завершение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать модуль `atexit` для регистрации функции обратного вызова, которая будет вызываться при завершении работы программы и удалит временную папку.

Пример кода:

```py
import atexit
import os
import shutil
from keyboard import add_hotkey
from os import startfile


def start():
    startfile(r'C:\Users\neptu\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9016\Discord.exe')


def cleanup_temp_folder():
    temp_folder = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath('.'))
    temp_path = os.path.join(temp_folder, '_MEI')
    shutil.rmtree(temp_path)


add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+8', start)

atexit.register(cleanup_temp_folder)

while True:
    pass
```

В этом примере функция `cleanup_temp_folder()` использует `shutil.rmtree` для удаления временной папки, которая создается pyinstaller во временном каталоге системы. Функция `cleanup_temp_folder()` затем зарегистрирована в модуле `atexit` с помощью `atexit.register()`, чтобы быть вызванной при завершении программы.

Обратите внимание, что `sys._MEIPASS` используется для получения временной папки, созданной при запуске скомпилированного exe-файла с помощью pyinstaller.
Надеюсь дядя Nymos вам помог!
Итак, дядя Nymos увидел твою просьбу и готов помочь.

Чтобы удалить временную папку после завершения скрипта, вы можете использовать блок `try/finally`, чтобы гарантировать выполнение кода удаления даже в случае возникновения исключения. Вставьте этот код в нужное место вашего скрипта:

```py
import shutil
import atexit

temp_folder = '<путь к временной папке>'

def remove_temp_folder():
    shutil.rmtree(temp_folder, ignore_errors=True)

# Зарегистрировать функцию удаления временной папки
atexit.register(remove_temp_folder)

# Ваш код иллюстрирующий бесконечное выполнение
while True:
    pass
```

Замените `<путь к временной папке>` на путь к созданной временной папке при запуске exe-файла. Функция `remove_temp_folder` использует `shutil.rmtree` для удаления папки и всех ее содержимого. Функция будет вызвана автоматически при завершении скрипта.

Чтобы убедиться, что все работает внутри exe-файла, удостоверьтесь, что путь к временной папке правильно указан и скомпилированный exe-файл находится в той же директории, что и временная папка.

Comment: спасибо большое. Я ещё не успел проверить, но уверен что это сработает. Только есть один момент, папка создаётся там же, где открывается exe файл. Поэтому нужно переделать немного. Как я понимаю нужно будет просто всё убрать, оставив только shutil.rmtree и atexit

Comment: У меня сработало только в самой консоли pycharm. Если я именно exe открываю, то не работает

Comment: @fanatskiLLa1 Я объяснил тебе

Comment: Спасибо огромное!